# SQL query in access joins, need it to also append where there is a new REF number

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables in access. The update is fine, but could I possibly also append any reference numbers that are not already in the sheet, in this same query?

```
UPDATE [UPDATEtable tester2]

INNER JOIN [Update2 Linked]     ON      

  [UPDATEtable tester2].[REF]   = [Update2 Linked].[REF]

set  

  [UPDATEtable tester2].[NAMES]     = [Update2 Linked].[NAMES] 
, [UPDATEtable tester2].[AMOUNT]  = [Update2 Linked].[AMOUNT]
```

Then my problem comes in with the "append" or Inserting of any new entries where the REF number isn't already in [UPDATEtable tester2]. I have tried to just add the following underneath the script above without success. It says missing operator?

```
INSERT INTO       [UPDATEtable tester2].[REF] , [UPDATEtable tester2].[NAMES] , [UPDATEtable tester2].[AMOUNT]  

SELECT  [REF] , [NAMES] , [AMOUNT]

FROM    [Update2 Linked]

WHERE [Update2 Linked].[REF] 

NOT IN 

(SELECT   [UPDATEtable tester2].[REF]   FROM    [UPDATEtable tester2])
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

For your first item, no you cannot combine update and append processes in same query. You can use macros or VBA to [DLookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) [REF] values beforehand and then logically decide the update or append action.

As for you query problem, in SQL INSERT INTO statements, you only specify the table name then list fields in parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO [UPDATEtable tester2] ([REF], [NAMES], [AMOUNT])
SELECT [REF], [NAMES], [AMOUNT]
FROM [Update2 Linked]
WHERE [Update2 Linked].[REF]
NOT IN
  (SELECT [UPDATEtable tester2].[REF] 
   FROM [UPDATEtable tester2]);
```

Alternatively, to avoid using the IN subquery, you can use the LEFT JOIN Null version:

```
INSERT INTO [UPDATEtable tester2] ([REF], [NAMES], [AMOUNT])
SELECT [Update2 Linked].[REF], [Update2 Linked].[NAMES], [Update2 Linked].[AMOUNT]
FROM [Update2 Linked]
LEFT JOIN [UPDATEtable tester2]
  ON [Update Linked].[REF] = [UPDATEtable tester2].[REF] 
WHERE [UPDATEtable tester2].[REF] Is Null;
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. I see the answers have been closed. I had something similar, with the left join way that I found somewhere else on S/O. Only difference was the second line "SELECT DISTINCT A.[REF], A.[NAMES], A.[AMOUNT]"

Comment: @gord thompson, thanks for the link. I had no idea what upserting was!